# Mongodb reads are so slow - flutter

Tags: mongodb, flutter

I have a problem with mongodb and flutter,
I use MongoDB Community server as local server and I use flutter for programming,
I'm building a chat app and I use nested queries to get the specific data I need,
I have three collections in mongodb, one for chat list, one for chat, one for users,
so I need to read data from users collection, read data from chat list collection, and read data from chat collection,
all of these reads are nested,
users -> chat list -> chat,
read all chats according to some chat lists own by a specific user,
so when I do this process It takes a long time to get the data,
even though the data are not that big and the server is local.

I have like 48 documents in chat list collection, 12 documents in users collection, and about 370 documents in chat collection.

I only used mongodb because I read on the internet that mongodb is super fast, that's why I used it,
if it's the database problem can you please suggest a fast database, I only store text in database.

This code below uses only chat collection to get data from and it takes about 5 - 10 seconds to finish getting the specified data:

```
    Future<Iterable<Map>> getCurrentUserChats(String title) async {
      List<Map> tempo = [];
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> _messages = [];
      await chatCollection
          .find(where.eq(TBtitle, title).and(where
              .eq(TBsender, getUserNumber())
              .or(where.eq(TBreceiver, getUserNumber()))))
          .forEach((element) {
        late var _owner;
        late var _side;
        if (element[TBsender] != getUserNumber()) {
          _owner = element[TBsender];
          _side = 'his';
        } else {
          _owner = element[TBreceiver];
          _side = 'my';
        }
        element.addAll({'owner': _owner});
        element.addAll({'side': _side});
        tempo.add(element);
      });
    return tempo.reversed;
    }
```

Comment: There is not nearly enough information here to begin speculating what might be wrong.  If you could focus on one specific operation that is slow, and provide the code for it, we might be able to help optimize the code.

Comment: Any database can fast or slow, it all depends on how it is configured and used. As @Joe advised, we would need more information to even begin helping. Perhaps a better approach for getting help would be to share the specific query that is not fast enough, details about the environment (such as the indexes on the collections and `explain` output for the query), and other context such as what your target runtime for the query is.

Comment: sorry for the late response, I added the code above, I think it should retrieve data super fast, and shouldn't take that much long.